# Delete cell after copied for 30 seconds

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my very simple VBA code to copy and paste specificed range in excel.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:G12,A84:G110 ").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("sheet1").Range("A112:G150").PasteSpecial
    Sheets("sheet1").Range("A112:G150").Copy
End Sub
```

I want to delete this range in Excel (`Sheets("sheet1").Range("A112:G150").Copy`) after it has been copied for 30 seconds. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Application.Wait` to wait for 30 seconds:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:G12,A84:G110").Copy
    Sheets("sheet1").Range("A112:G150").PasteSpecial
    Sheets("sheet1").Range("A112:G150").Copy

    Application.Wait Now() + 30 / 60 / 60 / 24

    Sheets("sheet1").Range("A112:G150").Clear
End Sub
```

Comment: I actually needed the 2nd copy as well. The purpose of this button is to copy the specified range then I am going to paste to email for reply.

Comment: @bys0202 I edited the answer to put the second copy back in.